# C segmentation fault - Array too large?

Tags: c

I am currently trying to write some image processing algorithms for large images in Standard C where I encountered some weird segmentation fault behaviour when trying to allocate memory for a large array. The following code already runs into a segmentation fault on my WSL instance:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char test[8640][15360];
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me understand what is going on? The numbers are not arbitrary, they are the image height and width in my production code.

Comment: This code will allocate the large array on the stack. Consider using dynamic allocation, e.g. using `malloc`.

Comment: You have a 130Mb large image? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Lundin It is a bitmap of a 16k resolution image. The filesize is actually three times as much.